# How to automatically resize JavaFX containers when window is maximized?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

Basically, I have the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

   <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="566.0" prefWidth="753.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.controller">
    <center>
        <JFXTabPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="TAB">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <children>
                                <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="495.0" prefWidth="753.0">
                                    <children>
                                        <StackPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                            <children>
                                                <HBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <JFXTreeView fx:id="treeView" />
                                                        <TableView  maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="277.0" prefWidth="753.0">
                                                            <columns>
                                                                <TableColumn maxWidth="-1.0" text="COL" />
                                                                <TableColumn text="COL" />
                                                                <TableColumn text="COL" />
                                                                <TableColumn text="COL" />
                                                                <TableColumn minWidth="0.0" text="COL" />
                                                                <TableColumn text="COL" />
                                                            </columns>
                                                            <columnResizePolicy>
                                                                <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                                            </columnResizePolicy>
                                                        </TableView>
                                                    </children>
                                                </HBox>
                                            </children>
                                        </StackPane>
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </Tab>
            </tabs>
        </JFXTabPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

The main class to load the FXML document:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane parent = (BorderPane)  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("document.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

When i maximize the window, the table and the rest of the containers don't resize accordingly. I tried to set `Max Width` and `Max Height` for all the containers to `MAX_VALUE` in SceneBuilder but nothing really happens. 
Is there a way to automatically expand the containers so that they can use all the space when the window is maximized ?

Comment: Could you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha done.

Comment: The code posted is not [mcve]

Comment: @c0der I removed all unnecessary and irrelevant parts from the original FXML file i have (Removed menus, items & containers). I only kept the necessary parts to reproduce the problem. I didn't include the main class that will load the FXML file, set the scene and show it because this is not something that will help in understanding the problem and finding the solution. It is something irrelevant and will only overcrowd the post with unnecessary code.

Comment: It should certainly be **M**inimal , but it should also be **V**erifiable : we should be able to copy paste and run it.

Comment: @c0der  Even though i have added an answer, you can still check out  the additional information i have included to make a MCVE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending some time investigating the problem. The steps that have corrected the issue are :
1- Setting all the anchor pane constraints to 0 (In the VBox tag) will allow for the child container to occupy all the space provided by the parent.

```
<VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
```

2- Setting the Hgrow attribute of the TabeView to Always will allow for the table to grow horizontally whenever it finds space.
3- For the rest of the containers, keeping the default settings and setting Max Height and Max Width to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start: a border pane that will grow with scene:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
    root.setCenter(new Text("center"));
    root.setTop(new Text("top"));
    root.setBottom(new Text("bottom"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    root.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    root.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I am writing the UI using an FXML document with a controller and i don't have access to the scene object instance. I know that i can inject the reference when i load the FXML (Using the returned controller reference) but it looks like a dirty hack. Is there another way to achieve it using only FXML ? i have included the FXML document.